# How to change settings of a base style from derived settings using BasedOn property

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I have simple style with ControlTemplate OrangeButton, and I have created another style OrangeButton2 BasedOn OrangeButton. I am trying to change the border properties, but WPF doesn't render the new border style defined in OrangeButton2. I tried the opposite also, where OrangeButton is based on OrangeButton2, with no change. Any idea what is actually happening here, and how to make it correct.

```
   <Style x:Key="OrangeButton" TargetType="Button" >
      <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11px"/>
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Name="border"
               BorderThickness="1"
               Padding="4,2"
               BorderBrush="DarkGray"
               CornerRadius="3"
               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
              <Grid >
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="contentShadow" Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}">
                </ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content"/>
              </Grid>
            </Border>                
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="OrangeButton2" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource OrangeButton}">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
    </Style>  
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource OrangeButton2}">Hello</Button>    
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You can reduce the XAML to the two important styles to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to define a `BorderBrush`, you will have to use it. In your `ControlTemplate` change

```
<Border Name="border"
    BorderThickness="1"
    Padding="4,2"
    BorderBrush="DarkGray"
    CornerRadius="3"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

to

```
<Border Name="border"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    Padding="4,2"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    CornerRadius="3"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

This will use the value you define for the `Style`.

Comment: What happens if the OrangeButton derives from OrangeButton2, instead

Comment: The result would be that OrangeButton2 would use the default .NET button template and OrangeButton would override it with your modified style. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to change the border property of OrangeButton with out modifying it. I am trying to do it programmatically so I can make the OrangeBUtton style derive from another style or create a new style which derives from OrangeButton. I have lots of controltemplates so modifying each one of them is not an option now.

Comment: Too bad. What about deriving from OrangeButton and overriding its ControlTemplate with the modification I suggested? Then you would have a "clean template" in OrangeButton2 and could set the border by Style.

Comment: There may be few instances where Brorder is hardcoded I can change those. But what about the scenarios where I don't have border at all in ControlTemplate, and I still don't see the properties getting applied. I mean if you just comment the Border section in OrangeButton, shouldn't OrangeButton2 override the properties.

Comment: No, if you remove the Border element, there would be no border at all. If a ControlTemplate exists, it overrides the previous template completly. If you can modify the template in OrangeButton, I would suggest to do it. You can do this without changing the appearance of OrangeButton by moving the hard coded values from Template to Style and use TemplateBinding.

Comment: Ok, will update the ones with hardcoded references, but if no border is defined at all in controltemplates, is it possible to change them at runtime in code, do you happen to know top of your mind, if you can.

Comment: If you want to place the border in the ControlTemplate, you will have to modify it. Otherwise you would have to modify the visual tree created by WPF at runtime and I would definitely not suggest this, if there's another way.